# Draw a box around some table elements based on the condition in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an index.html file which looks as follows:

```
span {
        outline: 2px solid black;   
    }

.wrapped {
    outline: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapped span {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

<body>

<div class="container">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col1</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col2</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col5</th>
        </tr>
        <script>var dictionary = {}</script>
        {% for b in obj %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
            <td><span class="wrapped"><span>{{ b.col2 }}</span></span></td>
            <td>{{ b.col3 }}</td>
            <script> if (!dictionary["{{ b.col2 }}"]) {
        dictionary["{{ b.col2 }}"] = [];
    }
    dictionary["{{ b.col2 }}"].push("{{ b.col3 }}");</script>
            <td>{{ b.col4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <script>
         delete dictionary[""];
console.log(dictionary)
for (var key in dictionary)
{

    if (dictionary[key].length > 1) {
        var name1 = []
        var id = []
        for (i in dictionary[key]) {    

            var reg1 = dictionary[key][i].split("(")[0];
            name1.push(reg1);
            var reg2 = dictionary[key][i].split("_")[1].match(/[A-Z0-9]*/i);  
            id.push(reg2[0]);
            }
    console.log(name1);
    console.log(id);
    }
}
</script>
        </table>
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

I'm reading a table from a mysql database which looks like this:

```
Col2   | Col3                   | Col4
1      | Name1(something_1234)  | Some_date
1      | Name1(something_3456)  | Some_date
2      | Name3(something_7890)  | Some_date
2      | Name4(something_0988)  | Some_date
```

The output of `dictionary` in the above snippet is as follows:

```
{'1': ['Name1(something_1234)', 'Name1(something_3456)'], '2': 'Name3(something_7890)', 'Name4(something_0988)']}
```

And `name1` and `id` returns the name part and the id part respectively from `col3` for each key, (i.e., `['Name1', 'Name1']` & `['1234', '3456']` for key `1`).

Now, I want to know how I could add css on top of the displayed table (kinda like a conditional css, like for all same col2 values add a box around it, then check values of it name parts, if they are same then add a box around them otherwise add separate boxes around then and similarly for the id parts as well), such that I get the following output:

[image: output]

UPDATE: Updated my code above. I'm able to draw box around each Col2 element. But I want to check if col2 cell's value is equal to the previous value then draw box around box together. And how to draw a box only around part of text in the cell i.e., around name and id part in Col3??

Comment: Maybe give each col a different class. What do you mean by (for all same col2 values)?

Comment: You could achieve what u showing in Col2 by adding classes to col2 cells, but what u showing in Col3 is possible only if u put names (e.g. "Name1") to a `<span>` element and use the classes to that name spans instead. Btw. you need 3 classes: `.top`, `.middle`, `.bottom`. Of course you need to program your logic of adding classes to cells and spans

Comment: @Joraid Please see the image attached in the question. That is what I mean by draw a box around "same" col2 values.

Comment: @Incredible Will the javascript part that I've written to get the name part and id part from the col3 values be useful at all here?

Comment: Yes, if you use it in the first `for` loop where the rows are generated. You must find the name and id, then put it to spans. You could store the name and id of currently generated row in the loop and in the next cycle compare it to previously stored values. This way you could see if a name or id is repeated.

Comment: @Incredible Okay but I still don't understand how the box will be created with css/html. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Incredible Updated my code to add the javascript where the rows are generated.

Comment: @akrama81 check my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Okay but I still don't understand how the box will be created with css/html. Can you show me an example?

Yes, I did something simmilar to your drawing in js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tq0u0876/

Now it's your turn to generate the HTML with a Blade syntax and JS.

---

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="border-top">1</span></td>
   <td>
     <span class="border-top">Name1</span>
     <span>(something_</span>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">1234</span>
     <span>)</span>
   </td>
   <td><span>some data</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="border-bottom">1</span></td>
   <td>
     <span class="border-bottom">Name1</span>
     <span>(something_</span>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">3456</span>
     <span>)</span>
   </td>
   <td><span>some data</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="border-top">2</span></td>
   <td>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">Name2</span>
     <span>(something_</span>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">7890</span>
     <span>)</span>
   </td>
   <td><span>some data</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="border-middle">2</span></td>
   <td>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">Name3</span>
     <span>(something_</span>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">0988</span>
     <span>)</span>
   </td>
   <td><span>some data</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span class="border-bottom">2</span></td>
   <td>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">Name4</span>
     <span>(something_</span>
     <span class="border-top border-bottom">7890</span>
     <span>)</span>
   </td>
   <td><span>some data</span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.border-top { 
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}

.border-middle {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
}

table { border-collapse: collapse; }
span { display:inline-block; line-height:26px; margin-bottom:-6px; }
td:nth-child(1) span { border-color:red; min-width:20px; }
td:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(1) { border-color:green; min-width:60px; }
td:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(3) { border-color:blue; min-width:60px; }
```